# Smooth movement using joystick in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to accomplish smooth movement with the Xbox Controller, however it is very snappy, even though snap is turned of and deadzone set to 0. Movement with keyboard however is very smooth, so I assume GetAxis does not work with a controller, it's always GetAxisRaw. So I switched to GetAxisRaw and tried to smooth everything out. Even with acceleration, the movement is still very jagged and snappy. Does anyone have an idea how to get a nice smooth movement with a controller, like keyboard + GetAxis?

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
CharacterController cc;

float acceleration = 0;

[SerializeField] float speed;
[SerializeField] float acclerationRate = 1;
private void Awake()
{
    cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

private void Update()
{
    float deadzone = 0f;
    Vector2 stickInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    if (stickInput.magnitude < deadzone)
        stickInput = Vector2.zero;
    else
        stickInput = stickInput.normalized * ((stickInput.magnitude - deadzone) / (1 - deadzone));

    if (stickInput.x != 0 || stickInput.y != 0)
    {
        acceleration += Time.deltaTime * acclerationRate;
        acceleration = Mathf.Clamp01(acceleration);
    }
    else
    {
        acceleration = 0;
    }

    cc.Move(new Vector3(stickInput.x, 0, stickInput.y) * speed * acceleration * Time.deltaTime);


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep track of your player's velocity and use [`MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) to adjust it based on the input. Don't forget to clamp your input's magnitude so your character doesn't travel diagonally faster than orthogonally in the event the player prefers keyboard input.

```
CharacterController cc;

[SerializeField] float speed;
[SerializeField] float acclerationRate = 1;
[SerializeField] float deadzone = 0f;

Vector3 velocity;

private void Awake()
{
    cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    velocity = Vector3.zero;
}

private void Update()
{

    Vector3 stickInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, 
            Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
 
    if (stickInput.magnitude < deadzone)
    }
        stickInput = Vector3.zero;
    }
    else
    {
        float clampedMag = Mathf.Min(1f, stickInput.magnitude);
        stickInput = stickInput.normalized * (clampedMag - deadzone) / (1f - deadzone);
    }

    velocity = Vector3.MoveTowards(velocity, stickInput, 
            accelerationRate * Time.deltaTime);

    cc.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```